# Import database error. Flask + SQLalchemy + SQLite deployment to Pythonanywhere fails

Tags: python, flask, deployment, wsgi, pythonanywhere

Failed to deploy flask application to python anywhere. Following their tutorial `https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/`

App.py is located at this path there `home/koti1/evo/app.py` , database.py, models.py and all other files are also there. Everything works fine on localhost.

Settings on pythonwnyehre :

```
 Source code:
/home/kotik1/evo

Working directory:
/home/kotik1/evo
```

WSGI configuration file:

```
import sys

path = '/home/kotik1/evo'
if path not in sys.path:
   sys.path.append(path)

from app import app as application
```

The error in log:

```
:Error running WSGI application
:ImportError: No module named 'database'
:  File "/var/www/kotik1_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 7, in <module>
:    from app import app as application
:
:  File "./app/app.py", line 6, in <module>
:    from database import db_session
```

Again, there no problems with sqlite database on localhost.

There is database.py file with such contents:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////tmp/test.db', convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_db():
    # import all modules here that might define models so that
    # they will be registered properly on the metadata.  Otherwise
    # you will have to import them first before calling init_db()
    #gitcommen
    import models
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

And as you see from logs, `init_db` from `database.py` is called in `app.py` by these line in the end of the file. :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
init_db()
app.run()
```

The error is in import line in app.py but I can't figure out the reason because on localhost everything is fine and all dependencies like sqlalhemy are installed . What may be the reason?

```
from database import db_session
```

Comment: I would try importing it with the full package name IE: from `exo.database import db_session` You also may need to make sure your `__init__.py` is importing `from .database import *`

Comment: Have you seen this guide?  http://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError